# debugging a published site asp.net webforms website

Tags: asp.net

Today our asp.net web site (not web application) errored on our production server. Luckily the latest source code fixed the issue. When we do a release, our senior dev forces us to put in a release mode and turn off debug in the web.config (due to security audits for PCI compliance). Is there a way you debug the website remotely from our office when it's been published in release mode?

Answer (score 1):

you might be better off using some sort of logging or error handler, like ELMAH.  Don't think you can debug a release mode dlls, as it doesn't include the pdb files.  Plus debugging a production site would lock the IIS worker process, so if you hit a breakpoint other users hitting the site would just get stuck waiting for you to release the breakpoint.

Comment: OK can I completely output stacking information as well as the state of variables. Depending on the native of the app, just the stack trace and error message may not be enough info to diagnose the problem. Besides afaik the inner exception doesn't gwt outputted by default.  I've have cases where the inner exception give me more info than the exception I could see